# PowerBuilder DataWindow retrieval arguments not working for SQL Server

Tags: sql, migration, powerbuilder

Earlier we were using Sybase as the back end. Now we are migrating to SQL server where as front end remains the same i.e. PowerBuilder.

**Issue :**
I have a DataWindow code which takes two retrieval arguments adt_from_date and adt_to_date. Both Date format. This works fine for PB-Sybase combination, but throws an error 37000 for SQL server.

Here is our code. If I hard-code the dates. i.e. for e.g. if I replace :adt_from_date by '20141001'. The code works fine.

```
SELECT   A.MEMBER_NO AS 'MEMBER_NO',  
ROUND(SUM(TRANSACTION_CHARGES),2) as 'AMOUNT',  
            SUBSTRING(DATENAME(MM, :adt_from_date ),1,3) +'-'+substring(convert(varchar,datepart(YY, :adt_from_date )),3,2) as 'REASON'  

FROM        TRAN_SERVICE_TAX_DRV A,
            MEMBER_MASTER B

WHERE   A.MEMBER_NO = B.MEMBER_NO

AND     A.TRADE_DATE BETWEEN :adt_from_date AND :adt_to_date

GROUP BY A.MEMBER_NO
```

Please suggest something on this.

Comment: What driver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you look at the error text being loaded into the transaction instead of just the number; it will probably be much more helpful. If we're talking about SQLState 37000, that doesn't narrow it down much.

If that doesn't shed some light on it, I'd look at tracing either on the PowerBuilder side, or on the database side. Starting on the PB side probably makes most sense. If you're just running this DataWindow from the IDE, the trace is just a checkbox on the connection properties. If in the app, replace your "DBMS='xxx'" with "DBMS='tra xxx'" (there are other options described in the Connecting to your Database manuals).

Good luck.